# How to concatenate values present in the list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

new_dict = [{'confidence': 0.7181452631261411, 'sentence': 'In general working from home is not permitted due to the complexity of the responsibilities as well as infrastructural and other issues that arise if the leader functions from anywhere outside the office premises ', 'extraction': {'arg1': {'text': 'the other issues', 'offsets': [[53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68]]}, 'rel': {'text': 'arise', 'offsets': [[75, 76, 77, 78, 79]]}, 'arg2s': [], 'context': None, 'negated': False, 'passive': False}}, {'confidence': 0.7181452631261411, 'sentence': 'In general working from home is not permitted due to the complexity of the responsibilities as well as infrastructural and other issues that arise if the leader functions from anywhere outside the office premises ', 'extraction': {'arg1': {'text': 'the infrastructural issues', 'offsets': [[53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78]]}, 'rel': {'text': 'arise', 'offsets': [[85, 86, 87, 88, 89]]}, 'arg2s': [], 'context': None, 'negated': False, 'passive': False}}]

```
if len(new_dict) == 0:
        yield sent
    else:
        for dict_value in new_dict:
            for second_list in dict_value['extraction']['arg2s']:
                test = "".join(str(x) for x in dict_value['extraction']['arg1']['text'] + " " + dict_value['extraction']['rel']['text'])

                arg2 = "".join(second_list['text'])
                new_result = "".join(filter(None,test + " " + arg2))


            yield new_result
```

I want to concatenate the all strings which is present in the text field.  Can someone help me.
I am expecting output as
["the other issues arise",
"the infrastructural issues arise"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work.

```
    conc=[]
    for i in new_dict:
        text=i['extraction']['arg1']['text']+" "+i['extraction'] ['rel']['text']
        for j in i['extraction']['arg2s']:
            text=text+" "+j['text']
        conc.append(text)
```

Comment: I want list  'arg2s': [] need to be considered because sometimes it contains a text field which i need to concatenate.

Comment: You can use try, except but the thing is arg1 is dictionary and arg2 is list, need little more information about arg2, if you can provide an example of arg2 having text it'll be easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Due to charector limit size i cannot post y data here. I am attaching the colabedit link. Please review my code and help me if am going in right way to retrieve the string or not.   http://collabedit.com/7k2pm